# How to generate a random n-bit number where n is arbitrary

Tags: c++

For example, if n is 32 bits, a random number between 2147483648 and 4294967295 would be generated. If n was fixed, I would just use a RNG and uniform_int_distribution to do so. However, the value of n is only known during run time. Is there a way to set the range of uniform_int_distribution based on n or is there another approach to this?

Comment: How does 32 bits correlate with that range? Normally a 32-bit random value is between 0 and 4,294,967,295. You're describing a...31-bit number? Sort of?

Comment: If n <= 32 you can solve your problem with masking and shifting the bits from a uniform distribution over all 2^32 values.

Comment: If you can express your upper and lower bounds in terms of *n* then you can create a `uniform_int_distribution` between those two values. Do you mean the minimum is `1 << (n - 1)` and the maximum is `(1 << n) - 1`? You can dynamically initialize your generator at run-time, the range does not have to be hard-coded.

Comment: @nneonneo Be careful! "Masking and shifting bits" will almost certainly break the uniformity of the distribution.

Comment: You can always generate `n` 1-bit random numbers

Comment: @tadman sorry for the confusion. What I mean is if n is 32 bits, only numbers with MSB set to 1 is allowed. So 2147483648 will get 10000000000000000000000000000000, which is the lowest bound.

Comment: @AdrianMole: actually, if the source distribution is uniform over 2^32 possibilities, and you are shifting it into a distribution over 2^n possibilities, the uniformity will be preserved since you’re just throwing out bits.

Comment: That makes more sense. Then just initialize your generator between those two bounds and you're good to go. Don't over-complicate this.

Comment: @tadman the issue i am having is n can be any number between 1 and 32. Is there a way to set the lower and upper bounds of n for the distribution?

Comment: I explained how you compute that in an earlier comment.

Comment: @tadman thank you, I am unfamiliar with the bitwise shift operator so I overlooked your comment. I will look it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the range you are asking for:

```cpp
uint32_t n = 30; // Change to whatever value you need - at runtime.
uint32_t umin = uint32_t(uint64_t(1) << uint64_t(n - 1));   // Extend to 64-bit ints...
uint32_t umax = uint32_t((uint64_t(1) << uint64_t(n)) - 1); //... to prevent overflow...
                                                            // ... of INTERMEDIATES!
std::uniform_int_distribution uirnd(umin, umax);
```